# bootstrap bootbox show variable in message within form text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to output a variable I have within a readonly formfield (text):

```
$(function() {
  return $("#buy_order_btn").click((function(_this) {
    return function() {
      var price;
      price = $("#order_bid_price").val();
      return bootbox.dialog({
        title: "Confirm Buy Order",
        message: "Price: <input type=\"text\" readonly=\"readonly\" value=\"HERE COMES THE PRICE VALUE FROM ABOVE\">"
      });
    };
  })(this));
});
```

How to do this?

Comment: You mean you want this:  `message: "Price: <input type=\"text\" readonly=\"readonly\" value=\"" + price + "\">";`  ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  return $("#buy_order_btn").click((function(_this) {
    return function() {
      var price;
      price = $("#order_bid_price").val();
      return bootbox.dialog({
        title: "Confirm Buy Order",
        message: "Price: <input type=\"text\" readonly=\"readonly\" value=\"" + price + "\">"
      });
    };
  })(this));
});
```

I would consider using ' when I have html inside the string, just so it can be readable as a normal html text